# Kafka Streams rebalancing latency spikes on high throughput kafka-streams services

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

we are starting to work with Kafka streams, our service is a very simple stateless consumer.

We have tight requirements on latency, and we are facing too high latency problems when the consumer group is rebalancing. In our scenario, rebalancing will happen relatively often: rolling updates of code, scaling up/down the service, containers being shuffled by the cluster scheduler, containers dying, hardware failing.

One of the first tests we have done is having a small consumer group with 4 consumers handling a small amount of messages (1K/sec) and killing one of them; the cluster manager (currently AWS-ECS, probably soon moving to K8S) starts a new one. So, more than one rebalancing is done.

Our most critical metric is latency, which we measure as the milliseconds between message creation in the publisher and message consumption in the subscriber. We saw the maximum latency spiking from a few milliseconds, to almost 15 seconds.

[image: LAG WAIT TIME]

[image: end to end latency]

[image: processed msgs/sec]

We also have done tests with some rolling updates of code and the results are worse, since our deployment is not prepared for Kafka services and we trigger a lot of rebalancings. We'll need to work on that, but wondering what are the strategies followed by other people for doing code deployment / autoscaling with the minimum possible delays.

Not sure it might help, but our requirements are pretty relaxed related to message processing: we don't care about some messages being processed twice from time to time, or are very strict with the ordering of messages.

We are using all default configurations, no tuning.

We need to improve this latency spikes during rebalancing.
Can someone, please, give us some hints on how to work on it? Is touching configurations enough? Do we need to use some concrete parition Asignor? Implement our own?

What is the recommended approach to code deployment / autoscaling with the minimum possible delays?

Our Kafka version is 1.1.0, after looking at libs found for example kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0-cp1.jar, we installed Confluent platform 4.1.0.
In the consumer side, we are using Kafka-streams 2.1.0.

Thank you for reading my question and your responses.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please share your grafana dashboard? 
And how do I export the data required by it?

Comment: Would standby replicas help in this case? https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/architecture.html#streams_architecture_recovery

Comment: Standby replicas, according to the docs, is intended for make recovering state of stateful services faster. The problem we experience, since our service is stateless, is the lag with rebalancing, no state migration is involved.

So, I think standby replicas won't help.

Comment: @jarias As Ankur asked, would you please share dashboard and how did you export these data?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't share the dashboard. But there is nothing fancy or sophisticated on it.
We have all metrics on OpenTSDB exported from our Java processes and then accessed from Grafana. Standard OpenTSDB+Grafana stuff

Comment: @jarias is this rebalance metric exported from clients or brokers?

Comment: In our case we are using client metric for rebalance.
I don't know if it can be get from the broker.

We use the ConsumerRebalanceListener to report metrics: https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html

Answer (score 5):

If the gap is introduced mainly from the rebalance, meaning that not triggering the rebalance but just left AWS / K8s to do their work and resume the bounced instance and pay the unavailability period of time during the bounce --- note that for stateless instances this is usually better, while for stateful applications you'd better make sure the restarted instance can access to its associated storage so that it can save on bootstrapping from the changelog.

To do that:

In Kafka 1.1, to reduce the unnecessary rebalance you can increase the session timeout of the group so that coordinator became "less sensitive" about members not responding with heartbeats --- note that we disabled the leave.group request since 0.11.0 for Streams' consumers (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4881) so if we have a longer session timeout, the member leaving the group would not trigger rebalance, though member rejoining would still trigger one. Still one rebalance less is better than none.

In the coming Kafka 2.2 though, we've done a big improvement on optimizing rebalance scenarios, primarily captured in KIP-345 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-345%3A+Introduce+static+membership+protocol+to+reduce+consumer+rebalances). With that much fewer rebalances will be triggered with a rolling bounce, with a reasonable config settings introduced in KIP-345. So I'd strongly recommend you to upgrade to 2.2 and see if it helps your case

Comment: Thanks Guozhang Wang, regarding the proposed solution for Kafka 1.1, increasing the session timeout would help us avoiding rebalancing, but at the cost of having some partitions (the ones assigned to the dead consumer) stale for a relatively long time.

What would be the pros/cons of doing exactly the opposite, decreasing the session timeout?

Comment: Since your application is stateless, maybe that is preferrable: the main cost of a rebalance is the task migration and corresponding task restoration time spent, but for stateless applications, such time should be short, so reducing the session timeout to let coordinator to be more sensitive and trigger rebalance sooner.

Answer (score 1):

There are several configuration changes required in order to significantly decrease rebalance latency, especially during deployment rollout

**1.Keep the latest version of Kafka-Streams**

Kafka-Streams rebalance performance becomes better and better over time. A feature improvement that worth highlighting is [Incremental cooperative rebalancing protocol](https://www.confluent.io/blog/cooperative-rebalancing-in-kafka-streams-consumer-ksqldb/). Kafka-Streams has this feature out of the box (since version 2.4.0, and with some improvements at 2.6.0), with default partition assignor `StreamsPartitionAssignor`.

**2.Add Kafka-Streams configuration property `internal.leave.group.on.close = true` for sending consumer leave group request on app shutdown**

By default, Kafka-Streams doesn't send consumer leave group request on app graceful shutdown, and, as a result, messages from some partitions (that were assigned to terminating app instance) will not be processed until session by this consumer will expire (with duration `session.timeout.ms`), and only after expiration, new rebalance will be triggered. In order to change such default behavior, we should use the internal Kafka Streams config property `internal.leave.group.on.close = true` (this property should be added during Kafka Streams creation `new KafkaStreams(streamTopology, properties)`). As the property is private, be careful and double-check before upgrading to a new version if the config is still there.

**3.Decrease the number of simultaneously restarted app instances during deployment rollout**

Using Kubernetes, we could control how many app instances are created with a new deployment at the same time. It's achievable by using properties [max surge](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-surge) and [max unavailable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable). If we have tens of app instances, default configuration will rollout multiple new instances and at the same time, multiple instances will be terminating. It means that multiple partitions will require reassignment to other app instances, and multiple rebalances will be fired, and it will lead to significant rebalance latency. The most preferable configuration for decreasing rebalance duration is changing these configurations to `max surge = 1` and `max unavailable = 0`.

**4.Increase the number of topic partitions and app instances with a slight excess**

Having a higher number of partitions will lead to decreased throughput per single partition. Also, having a higher number of app instances, restart of a single one will lead to smaller Kafka lag during rebalancing. Also, make sure that you don't have frequent up-scaling and down-scaling of app instances (as it triggers rebalances). If you have a few up-scaling and down-scaling per hour, seems it's not a good configuration for a minimal number of instances, so you need to increase it.

For more details please take a look at the article [Kafka-Streams - Tips on How to Decrease Re-Balancing Impact for Real-Time Event Processing On Highly Loaded Topics](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-streams-tips-on-how-to-decrease-rebalancing)